# How to get score for each base model with ensemble model from stacking

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, ensemble-learning

I have created a `Stacking Ensemble Model`. The model is given below

```
def get_stacking():
    level0 = list()
    level0.append(("DT", DecisionTreeRegressor()))
    level0.append(("DT-2", DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=2)))
    level1 = LinearRegression()
    model = StackingRegressor(estimators=level0, final_estimator=level1)
    return model
```

I want to get the `score` for each base model and the final ensemble model's score. So, I am using (with `estimators_`) the below code to access the `base model`

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    DATASETS = {"Dataset": generate_data}
    models = get_stacking()
    for dataset_name, generate_dataset in DATASETS.items():
        dfs = []
        for i, model in models.estimators_:
                df = analyse(
                    generate_dataset=generate_dataset,
                    regressor=model,
                    reg_name=i)
```

But, I am getting an error `AttributeError: 'StackingRegressor' object has no attribute 'estimators_'`

Could you tell me why I am getting the error and how can I solve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't fitted the stacked model.  The attribute `estimators_` contains the fitted base estimators after fitting; the parameter `estimators` contains the unfitted base estimators.

Comment: If I use `estimators` before fit OR `estimators_` after fit (does they same concept)? Or they are totally different (as we are using before and after fit).

Comment: Since you want a score for the base estimators, you need to fit them first, either manually or by fitting the ensemble.

Comment: Thank you very much. If I use this code `for model in models.estimators_:` I am getting the base model (one by one) after feeding the ensemble model. I also need to get the base model name (DT, DT_2, etc.).  Any idea, how I can get the base model name? I am trying this `for i, model in models.estimators_:` but not working (even getting an error)

Comment: You could use the `named_estimators_` attribute instead, probably as `for name, est in model. named_estimators_.items():`, though I haven't tried it.